# How to extract triples from a sentence, and the triples should be existant in Wikidata

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, wikidata, knowledge-graph, triples

I have a sentence, and I want to use some tools to automatically extract a triple (triples) from the sentence. The triple(s) should be already existant in Wikidata. Is there any tool from Wikidata that can automatically do this, better in a Python style?

I know there are already some NLP libraries from OpenAI or Stanford to do entity recognition, but I am just wondering whether there is a Wikidata API that can directly do this job.

E.g., **Sentence**: NYU is located at New York. **Triple**: [NYU,located,New York]

Thanks!